# When using sentry dsn, the application does not finished

Tags: spring, sentry

I'm using Spring ApplicationRunner And k8s cronjob.

I'm using logback and sentry dsn to monitoring.

IfI don't use sentry dsn, the application will finished with exit code 0.

However, when I use sentry dsn, all tasks are successfully finished, but application is not terminated in that state and are still running.

In ApplicationRunner, I use Spring Kafka Producer.

How can I solve it?

```
@Component
class MyApplicationRunner(val myService: MyService) : ApplicationRunner {

    override fun run(args: ApplicationArguments?) {
        myService.send()
    }
}
```

```
@Service
class MyService{

    fun send() {
        // send kafka producer
    }
```

logback-spring.xml

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="Console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}] [%15.15thread] [%-5level] %logger{36}:%L - %msg %n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <springProfile name="json-log">
        <appender name="JsonConsole" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
            <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
                // implement logs
            </encoder>
        </appender>

        <root level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="JsonConsole"/>
        </root>
    </springProfile>

    <springProfile name="sentry-log">
        <appender name="Sentry" class="io.sentry.logback.SentryAppender">
            <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
                <level>WARN</level>
            </filter>
        </appender>

        <root level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="Sentry"/>
        </root>
    </springProfile>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

I'm running Application with SENTRY_DSN="my-dsn" and spring-profile=json-log,sentry-log

When I run Application not using SENTRY_DSN env,

```
// process success

Process finished with exit code 0
```

But When I run Application with SENTRY_DSN env,

```
// process success

// But process not finished and Application Still running doing nothing.
```